# Check if ONE array element contains a string

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, indexof

Is it possible to search for a string within each element of an array.

So if I have

```
var arr =["select 1", "select 2", "unselect 1"];
```

I want to see which array elements have "1" in them then remove the ones that dont. This is the code I have but it is not working.

```
var RowNum = ( $('table.input-table > tbody > tr').length);
var type = [];
for(var i=0; i<=(RowNum - 1); i++){
    type.push( $("table.input-table > tbody > tr").eq(i).html());
};
alert(type.length);

for(var i = (type.length - 1); i >= 0 ; i--){
    var SpliceVal = 0;

    for(var ii = 0; ii <= (Req.length -1); ii++){
        if(type[i].indexof(Req[ii]) == -1){
            SpliceVal += 1;    
        };  
    };

    if(SpliceVal == Req.length){
        type.splice(i, 1);
    };
};
alert(type.length);
```

The first alert(type.length); returns a 7.
Req.length = 3

The second alert(type.length); should return a 3

The code will partially run until I get to the line:

```
if(type[i].indexof(Req[ii]) == -1)
```

I get an error saying **TypeError: type[i].indexof is not a function**

Any help is appreciated

Comment: Do you mean `["select 1", "select 2", "unselect 1"]`?

Comment: its `indexOf` not `indexof`.

Comment: Yes that is what I mean.

Comment: Tip: semicolons don’t belong after blocks. (The ones after `for` and `if`, here.)

Comment: That was the issue on having the capital O, Thanks! I guess when you have been staring at it for an hour you miss those things.

Answer (score 0):

I would use filter;

```
var containsOne = function(el) {

   return el.indexOf('1') !== -1;
}

var filtered = ['select', 'select', 'select1'].filter( containsOne );

//returns 'select1'
```

http://jsfiddle.net/8vmjb1Lt/

Answer (score 0):

If you are dead set on using splice instead of another method:

```
var arr =["select 1", "select 2", "unselect 1", "uneselect 2", "select 1"];

for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    if (arr[i].indexOf("1") > -1) {
        arr.splice(i, 1);
        if (i !== 0) {i--;}
    }
}
```

[Updated JSFIddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hmfrzkca/2/).

*This will modify the original array*

Comment: The problem here is that the index is thrown off base once you splice the array. It's no longer pointing to the right position. Look at this fiddle when you introduce another array value with '1': http://jsfiddle.net/hmfrzkca/1/

Comment: @bencripps Ah, didn't catch that.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the exact thing you need. Use jquery **grep()** function by which you can get the list of elements that satisfy the your condition as shown below:

```
// Original array
var arr =["select 1", "select 2", "unselect 1"];

// Here, after executing this function your original array will have only
// elements having 1 in them
arr = jQuery.grep(arr, function(value) {
           if(value.indexOf("1") > 0){
              return true;
           }else{
              return false;
           }
      });
```